Cannot get Docker container with typesense to run without exiting
I am trying to turn a laptop I have into a little server to host Typesense on. The computer is running Windows 11 Home. I have installed Docker and it appears to be running. I then type "docker run -d -p 8181:8181 --name my-typesense -v C:/Users/timsu/typesense-data:/data/typesense typesense/typesense:26.0" in the command prompt and press enter. The folder "typesense-data" is created by Docker, but then the container just exits. The container log line 2 says "Invalid configuration: Data directory is not specified." despite the fact that it literally just successfully created the directory for the data.
I'm sorry I don't have any screen shots to share, there's really nothing to share beyond what I typed above. I am absolutely happy to add some if there is something in particular any responder needs to see.
Also I know that using a laptop this way probably isn't the best idea but I really need it for development, I don't want to have to pay for typesense cloud just for development, but I need a good search engine in my app. Any other ideas for that?

According to the https://hub.docker.com/r/typesense/typesense and the logs for the container as following:
# docker logs my-typesense
Typesense 26.0
Invalid configuration: Data directory is not specified.
Command line usage: ./typesense-server --data-dir=string --api-key=string [options] ...

you should provide --data-dir and --api-key parameters, you can try to start you container with the command like below, it should works:
docker run -d -p 8181:8181 --name my-typesense -v C:/Users/timsu/typesense-data:/data/typesense typesense/typesense:26.0 --data-dir /data/typesense --api-key=abc 


I think the issue could be typesense not knowing where to find the file created by Docker. Try using the -e flag to specify the environment variable for the data dir. -e TYPESENSE_DATA_DIR=your_dir/typesense-data

I tried that, just adding it to the end of the command, and it did the exact same thing. "Invalid configuration: Data directory is not specified. I think I might just wipe the laptop and put Ubuntu on it. Typesense is built to run on Linux anyway.
